# Not getting currency symbol and locale code for few currency codes in java 7

Tags: java, jar, locale, java-7, currency-formatting

Unable to get currency symbols and locale codes for few of the currency codes in `Java 7`. example: Currency codes.

```
AFN,
AMD,
ANG,
AOA,
AUD,
AWG,
AZN, etc..
```

and tried with `DecimalFormat.getAvailableLocales()` also instead of `NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()` but no use.

following is the code to get currency symbols.

```
package com.test.testandbackups;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CurrencyUtils {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String currencyCode = "INR";
        String ss = currencySymbol(currencyCode);

        System.out.println(ss);

    }

    public static String currencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
        String currencySymbol = null;
        currencySymbol = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode).getSymbol(
                getLocale(currencyCode));
        return currencySymbol;
    }

    private static Locale getLocale(String currencyCode) {
        for (Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
            String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)
                    .getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
            if (currencyCode.equals(code)) {
                return locale;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read that these currencies are supported?

Comment: No they told it will support for 77 currency for my requirement i have around 160 currency codes. is this any way to get dynamically for all the codes?

Comment: Build your own map with Code -> Symbol.

Comment: https://github.com/killbill/killbill-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/killbill/billing/catalog/api/Currency.java           like this map is preferable to maintain ?